# Linking two excel datasheet together using python

Tags: excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to link two excel datasheet together. So that if a cell from the first datasheet is clicked, it opens data regarding the value of that cell from a second datasheet. Here is an example for further clarification.

This is my first datasheet

```
0  2011    A1     SS    FF
1  2100    A5     SS    FF
2  2245    A3     RR    22
3  2945    A4     AA    3E
4  1140    A7     WE    7F
```

Now if I click A1 it should somehow provide me the data from the second datasheet, which should be NaN value and if i click A2 it should give me New York

```
A1    
A2      New York
A3  Newfoundland
A4       Ontario
A5         Texas
A6   Nova Scotia
```

I apologize for not being able to provide the original data frame, due to non-disclosure reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can link cells in other worksheets or workbook with XlsxWriter using the `write_url()` method with the `internal:` or `external:` uri. See the [XlsxWriter docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url).

This means that you will probably need to handle transferring the data outside of Pandas or else use Pandas and then overwrite the cells that you want to add links to using XlsxWriter.

Comment: I wasn't able to find many resources on Xlsxwriter docs regarding this or I just didn't understand properly. Would you be able to suggest me something?

Comment: There is a link to a quite detailed document section and example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link I went through that but I am having trouble creating a for loop to do that for all the values automatically.